# Postgresql REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY breaks the order

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, materialized-views

I have materialized view and it's very helpful. But after some time of using it I got issue that order in view is broken.
I created Matview as:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mat_view_sorted_products AS
      SELECT item.id, item.category_id FROM item
      INNER JOIN stock ON stock.item_id = item.id
      ORDER BY is_available DESC, views DESC;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX mat_view_index_id ON mat_view_sorted_products (id);
```

**ORDER BY in my case is very important thing**, so it works when I query from Matview and got sorted result of joining tables:

```
SELECT id FROM mat_view_sorted_products
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0; //got 100 sorted item ids by (is_available DESC, views DESC)
```

To refresh Materialized view I use: `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY mat_view_sorted_products`

But after some time and many refreshing iterations I saw that the order of matview records is broken. I thought that CONCURRENTLY updates values of free (of reading) records and do not change anything else.

Not? How is it working and how not to break ORDER while refreshing View?

P.S.

if I do REFRESH without CONCURRENTLY it restores normal sorting. It blocks view, cleans it and restores from select with order. But users do not have time to wait each time View is refreshing

**UPDATE:**

Of course I use order in my full SELECT statement:

```
SELECT id, name, views FROM item WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM mat_view_sorted_products
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0) ORDER BY is_available DESC, views DESC;
```

And it makes Sequence Scan on mat_view_sorted_products and I got 100 sorted items of all sorted items in view.
As I think the view creates like:

1. got 200 items ordered by ... from AS SELECT
2. inserted them into MatView
3. doing seq scan on 200 sorted items to get first 100 sorted items of all

Comment: Since materialised views are just tables, they don't have an order. You should specify the order in your `SELECT` query.

Answer (score 7):

No, the order is "not broken" because there is no such thing as the "order" of rows in a table.

Tables (and that includes materialized views) represent **unorder sets** and they have no implied order.

The **only** way to get a guaranteed sort order is to use `order by` in your SELECT statement. There is no alternative.

Remove the `order by` from your CREATE MATERIALIZED view statement and add it to your actual `SELECT` statement. Using LIMIT or OFFSET *without* an `ORDER BY` is a bug in your code.

Comment: Please watch Update

Comment: @НиколайАгеев Your subquery that uses `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` still doesn't use an `ORDER BY`. The order by in  the outer query is irrelevant for the limit and offset clauses

Comment: If I insert sorted result to new/clean view why I need to redo sort for records after it? Sequence scan will go through sorted table when selecting from view

Comment: Again: the **only** way to get a guaranteed sort order is to use `order by`. If you got a sorted result so far that was **pure coincidence** and could have changed anytime, e.g. when two Seq Scans on the same table happen at the same time. The **only** way to get a _guaranteed_ sort order is to use `ORDER BY` - there is **no** alternative.

Comment: So when I create materialized view I do not need to use ORDER in AS.. (as it pointless), yes?

Comment: In this case I see only way is to also add `is_available,views` to materialized view and sort by them in subquery. Or is there other solution in this situation?

Comment: Or adding to matview special UniqueId for sorting, like incrementing row number?

Comment: Adding a special Uniqueid for sorting will not guarantee order when you select. As @a_horse_with_no_name has tried to tell you **the *ONLY* way to guarantee sort order is "order by" in the select statement when retrieving the data**. Perhaps another voice will get you to listen.